# S3.php - writing files to Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm successfully using the following code to write files to S3:

```
<?php

        require_once 'S3.php';

        // Instantiate the class
        $s3 = new S3('AKIAJNIMGH2SZ5YRGTTA', 'dpIf3P7YsW38IosMTzX30KkMfTE7zkX77wuuIRzk', true, 's3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com');

        // dirname(__FILE__).'/S3.php' - this is the full server path to the file
        $s3->putObjectFile(dirname(__FILE__).'/S3.php', 'dating-images.goneglobal.com', '1000089762/new-file-user.jpg', S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);

?>
```

I've noticed the metadata defaults to 'text/plain'. How can I update this via php script to 'image/jpeg'? eg: is there an attribute I can add to the above code or an extra line?

thx

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the content-type as a string on this way:

```
$s3->putObjectFile(dirname(__FILE__).'/S3.php', 'dating-images.goneglobal.com', '1000089762/new-file-user.jpg', S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ, array(), 'image/jpeg');
```